# Publish/Public/private concept in stored procedures in a SQL Server solution develop in layers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

I fear you response going to be **NO**, but let me ask...

is there any way/best practice to mark/indicate the store procedures that should be kept internal to its own layer, and which can be used as interface to other layers, and which as external interface?

**Situation:**

We are developing a web solution in Node + SQL Server where security plays an important role, and also maintenance, and distributed development.

App consist of several layers (Access / Authorization / UserManagement / TaskManagement), and we are pursing high cohesion and low coupling between them (GRASP principles)

Each layers has SQL Server objects associated to it (tables, sequences and stored procedures, mainly) and we wonder if it could be an equivalent to the node concepts to separate them.

In node we build a single controller for each layer, then, **functions** (private) for all internal functionalities, **exports** for the functions that can be called from other layers, and **endPoints** for all published methods for web access

I know the published stored procedures can be managed trough roleAuthorisation, but no solution for Public and Private.

And even that, looking at all stored procedures is not possible to differentiate between neither type.

I fear you may say me, "call them spPbsh_* / spPblc_* and spPrvt__*  ...

**Maybe another solution or best practices ?**

And not, we will prefer to do not create separate databases per layer

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, could you create schemas for each "class" of SP - and then grant the appropriate permissions to your applications (denying them to your "private" schema, but granting them your "public")?

Comment: The schema thing only give the advantage of having classs.sp_its_own_name instead of dbo.class__sp_its_own_name, plus, (at least in my experience) no body is used to work with different schemas.

Comment: What I mean is to differentiate (both semantic and security wise) three types of "pieces of code" , those that are only internal to the layer and should not be accessed from outside its layer/module (**private**), those that can be acceses from other layers at SQL server (**public**), and those that can be acceses from node, buts only from the corresponding layer (**published**) . I hope in the next picture things get clearer :: http://imgur.com/a/zW4U9

Comment: And yes, I will prefer to do it, without need to develop a separate database for each of the layers, and control de accessibility trough two different authentication per database, one that allows "vertical" usage (from other layers within the SQL) and another that allows "horizontal" usage (from the corresponding layer from node)

Comment: That's not true - you can manage permissions at the schema level - so there's more of an advantage than merely organizing your stored procedures - and I think the permissions are what you need.  Do you have a difficulty or requirement that is NOT addressed by this approach?

Comment: @StanShaw : without making it too complicated (like a separate user for each layer), how would you set up the permissions to discriminate access? . Three stores procedures: the Publish ofCourse with permissions on the user for outside access, but I can not see  how to set up for an object to be accesible from its own schema, but not from the others, and viceversa, objects that can be accessed from other schemas.

Comment: You would have to use different users - and I'm not sure I would agree that's too complicated.  If your project requires that different permissions be granted to different "layers" of your application, then you need to set up the appropriate user permissions to achieve that.  I don't know of another way.

Comment: Yes, that I fear, a user of each layer: I will test it, and come to a lot of EXECUTE_AS_&_REVERTS ... , On the other hand, any suggestions about the naming conventions to discriminate among  ?? (Thanks a lot @StanShaw , you are being very helpful)

Comment: Why would you have to use `EXECUTE AS`?